# differences in prediction when testing trained keras model and using it on new samples

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, keras, scaletransform

I'm having troubles using a model which i already trained, saved and loaded to use. The problem is I'm getting different predictions when I'm using the model with new data (which is not part of the test data but comes from the same source).

**EDIT 1:** I realized I get different predictions when predicting whole test_data at once and when i predict each item of the test_data at a time.

This is how I generate the training and test data (i split it after)

```python
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    for i in range(100):        
        df[i] = df.data.shift(i)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    print(Counter(df['label'].values))

    Xa = np.array(df.drop(['label', 'Close', 'avg'], axis=1).values)

    data_for_scale = Xa[-1000:]

    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    Xa = scaler.fit_transform(Xa)

    Ya = np.array(df['label'].values)
```

Then I split the data into train and test to fit the model.
After training I test the model with the test data and get this kind of predictions:

```python
model.predict(x=X_test)
[ 0.64  0.17  0.19]
[ 0.24  0.76  0.  ]
[ 0.47  0.51  0.02]
[ 0.63  0.26  0.11]
[ 0.62  0.1   0.28]
[ 0.14  0.86  0.  ]
[ 0.36  0.63  0.01]
[ 0.57  0.37  0.06]
[ 0.45  0.53  0.02]
[ 0.18  0.82  0.  ]
[ 0.61  0.09  0.3 ]
#the maximum value in the 3th column is 0.45. nevermore!
```

To use the model i gather the data in this way:

```python
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaler.fit(data_for_scale)

    X_predict = np.array(df.data[current_position-100:current_position][::-1].values).reshape(1, -1)
    X_predict = scaler.transform(X_predict)
    prediccion = model.predict(X_predict.reshape(1, -1))[0]
    #**EDIT 1:** NOTICE i'm predicting just one item at a time
```

and the kind of predictions I get in this way are:

```python
[ 0.89  0.     0.10]
[ 1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.87  0.11  0.01]
[ 0.99  0.     0.00]
[ 0.30  0.69  0.   ]
[ 0.99  0.     0.00]
[ 0.61  0.     0.38]
[ 0.20  0.     0.79]
[ 0.39  0.     0.60]
[ 0.  0.  1.]
[ 0.00  0.     0.99]
[ 0.12  0.     0.87]
#here i get lots of values above 0.45 in the 3th column. This never 
#happens with the whole test_data...
```

Where could be my mistake? I already tried to save and reload the model but the prediction of the test data doesn't change so I don't think the mistake is saving/loading the model. I also tried to incorporate the new sample to predict into the test set, fit_scaling the whole set and extracting again the new data but the problem remains. 
Any hint is welcome
thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake?

Comment: Im getting totally different range of probability values mainly at the 3th column. While at the test_data i never get a value above 0.45, at the new data to predict i get lots of values above 0.45 and even 1. I cant be 100% sure there is a mistake but its definitely a different behavior.